# Collections AddAll Android

Tags: java, android, collections

I'm just starting out in java & android.

Below is my code, to add all the buttons in an activity then hide them.
Question: is their anyway to automatically add all the buttons in the activity without having to list each of them, I have looked at listA.addall but didn't understand how to add the activity as the collection.

The rational for this is I may wish to change the number of buttons and still have the code work.

```
public void setup2(){
    List<Button> listA = new ArrayList<Button>();

    listA.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button1));
    listA.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button2));
    listA.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button3));
    listA.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button4));
    listA.add((Button)findViewById(R.id.button5));

    for (Button item : listA)
        item.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your buttons are in a view group e,g, `LinearLayout`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
        if (v.getClass() == Button.class) {
            listA.add(v);
        }
}
```

`layout` is a reference to the layout containing the buttons.

This simply iterates over each child view in the layout, compares it's class type with `Button` and adds it to your collection if it is.

Comment: Simon, I like the approach, but not sure how to reference the layout. I tried creating an int to hold layout then had issues with getChileCount() not being considered as part of the method.

Comment: Give the layout containing the buttons an ID, like any other view in your XML and use `layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutContainingTheButtons);`

Comment: Thanks Simon, looks simple when you put it like that.
Here is the final working code:

    public void setup3(){
  List<Button> listA = new ArrayList<Button>();
  LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutButtons);
  
  for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
         View v = layout.getChildAt(i);
         if (v.getClass() == Button.class) {
          Log.e("QuickLook", "Found Button to add: " + v);
             listA.add((Button) v);
         }
  }
 }

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is probably the cleanest way of doing it. But if your buttons are all similarly id named (button_1, button_2 etc) You could search via string instead of direct ID reference. The following is an example of fetching a button by string:

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("button_%i", "id", getPackageName());
Button addButton = (Button) findViewById(resID);
```

Then you could loop around all your buttons.

Comment: Amorgos, thank you for your answer, I didn't know about the
    button_%i
This approach I may use elsewhere.